# The AOuth2 Authorization server does not insert token in the given database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

There is some configuration class in Authorization server:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String datasourceUrl;

    @Value("${spring.database.driverClassName}")
    private String dbDriverClassName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String dbUsername;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String dbPassword;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(datasourceUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource());
    }
}
```

and the another class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AccountUserDetailsService accountUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new HashingClass();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return accountUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/resources/**");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean())
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


}
```

and the third class is:

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class AuthServerOAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final AppConfig appConfig;

    @Autowired
    public AuthServerOAuth2Config(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AppConfig appConfig) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.appConfig = appConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(appConfig.dataSource());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        /*
         * Allow our tokens to be delivered from our token access point as well as for tokens
         * to be validated from this point
         */
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(appConfig.tokenStore()); // Persist the tokens in the database
    }
}
```

and the client application is like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController
@Configuration
public class SocialApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri}")
    private String accessTokenUri;

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(HttpServletResponse response, Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/index.html", "/getEmployees.jsp").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails() {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails details = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        details.setClientId(clientId);
        details.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        details.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
        return details;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and its application.yml file is:

```
server:
  port: 8090

security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: web
      clientSecret: secret
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/authorize
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8081/auth/user

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

When I request http://localhost:8090/user (this rest is owned client) I redirected to Authorization server and I can login successfully after login again I am redirected to the client with a code, but client is not able to exchange access token with the given code. and the following exception is raised on the browser:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback. Mon Dec 17 09:47:27 IRST 2018 There was an
>   unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401). Authentication
>   Failed: Could not obtain access token

And I query from DB:

```
select * from oauth_access_token
```

or

```
select * from oauth_client_token
```

The two above tables are empty.

Where is wrong? I am really confused.

**EDIT**

The application.properties file of AOuthrization server:

```
server.port=8081
server.context-path=/auth
security.basic.enabled=false

# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================

# Set here configurations for the database connection

# Connection url for the database w/createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.192.129:1521:hamed
spring.database.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
#spring.jpa.database = MySQL
#spring.datasource.platform = mysql

# Database - data initialization
spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = test
spring.datasource.password = test

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Transactions
spring.jpa.open-in-view = false

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

and the its pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>r05</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and the version of spring boot is:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

Comment: You have a lot going on here, and it will be difficult for the community to parse what's going on. Take a few minutes to pare this down to a minimal example that still reproduces the issue, and you'll get your answer faster. For example, I don't suppose that `guava`, the client app, `AppUserDetailsService`, or `HashingClass` are part of the equation here.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are using spring-boot and to me seems like you can clean up your code a little, for instance, all this `DataSource` config may not be necessary.

As for your problem, it could be related to the class `AuthServerOAuth2Config` where you are injecting `AppConfig` instead of `DataSource` and `TokenStore`, making this change can solve your problem.

Here you can find a sample auth service I did a while ago https://github.com/marcosbarbero/spring-security-authserver-sample

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem by removing two lines of application.yml of client application.
These two lines are:

```
  authenticationScheme: query
  clientAuthenticationScheme: form
```

Why these two lines cause problem, I do not know.